# Google Chrome dev tools variable tip bubble too little to see the content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have just now sent the following message to Google Chrome developer:

Chrome version: 54.0.2840.59 m

> As you know, when debugging a web page with javascript, the Chrome
> debugger allows to pause the execution of the code on breakpoints. In
> this moment is possible to move the mouse onto a variable to see what
> value has in: when the mouse is on the variable chrome code
> inspector/debugger shows a little tip showing the variable value.
>
> The problem is that such little bubble tip sometimes is toooo little
> and it is not possible to see the content.
>
> Please correct its size (make it resizable) to make possible to read
> its content or it isn't useful.
>
> Thanks

How can I solve this issue?

### Edits

Before the last update was working perfectly (or at least I didn't see anything wrong in its behavior!), but now the following image shows the issue that sometimes happens:

[image: Example.png]

---

As shown into the above img, part of the bubble tip content is shown, part is hidden, and it is not possible to scroll the bubble tip neither up|down nor left|right: scrollbars are greyed. Sometimes scrollbars don't appear at all.

Comment: I wonder if it is font-scaling/zoom level bug.

Comment: I didn't any modification to zoom factor or font scaling to the chrome devtools panel. So I'd tend to exclude it, nevertheless I can't be sure: might be the "bug" manifests itself even without doing any of such changes... I don't know... yet...

Comment: Yeah, I also saw this recently. Normally I have scroll bars turned off, but surprisingly when turning them on DevTools doesn't adjust the UI accordingly.

Comment: @MattZeunert: I use scroll bars turned on. So I'm not able to answer about your observation on my experience. But the suspect is that both chrome devtools behaviors could be part of the same problem of the OP. Might be that devtools has a little bug that doesn't allow resize properly some variable contents tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the tool tip as per the animation below:

[image: Scrollable tool tip]

Comment: I edited my post by adding a screenshot to show the issue

Comment: and I modified some content in it to generalize the behaviour cause sometimes happens not only for the var types I wrote before, so I thought it was better to generalize. It seems a chrome issue to me.

Comment: I'll have to check it out again when I'm at a computer again. Have you tried it in Chrome Canary in case it's an issue that has already been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround could be adding the variable to the watch list:

### Procedure:

1. right click on the variable
2. Into right click menu click on "Add selected text to watches"

This allows to keep an eye on the watchlisted var contents, even if they hidden into the bubble tip.

It is not completely handy, but works.